# Construction of vector bundle on archimedean analogue of Fargues-Fontaine curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

This is a question about a construction in the first lecture of a seminar on the Fargues-Fontaine curve, given by Jacob Lurie. The notes are available [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/ffcurve/Lecture1-Overview.pdf).

In section 5, Lurie introduces the twistor projective line $\mathbb P^1_{tw}$, the non-trivial real form of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$, as an archimedean analogue of the Fargues-Fontaine curve. I'll paraphrase the part I am confused about, which explains how to associate to a smooth projective variety $Y$ over $\mathbb C$ the pure Hodge structure on $H^n_{sing}(Y(\mathbb C); \mathbb C)$:

> The map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C \cong \{ \infty \} \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$ induces a closed immersion of $\mathbb R$-schemes $i: \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^1_{tw}$, which picks out a "point at infinity". We identify the formal completion of $\mathbb P^1_{tw}$ along $i$ with the formal scheme $\operatorname{Spf} \mathbb C[[\lambda]]$.
>
> Consider the trivial vector bundle $\mathcal E = H^n_{sing}(Y(\mathbb C); \mathbb R) \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_{tw}}$ on $\mathbb P^1_{tw}$. The global sections of $\mathcal E$ over the formal disk $\operatorname{Spf} \mathbb C[[\lambda]]$ can be identified with the $n$th hypercohomology group of the de Rham complex
> $$\Omega^0_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d} \Omega^1_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d}\Omega^2_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d} \cdots.$$

How are the sheaves $\Omega^i_Y[[\lambda]]$ defined and how do they relate to Y? Why is the above statement true? It seems to rely on a Hodge decomposition for $\operatorname{Spf} \mathbb C$, but I don't know why there should be one.

> We can then construct a new vector bundle which is isomorphic to $\mathcal E$ away from the image of $i$, and whose global sections over the formal completion $\operatorname{Spf} \mathbb C[[\lambda]]$ are given by the $n$th hypercohomology of the larger complex
> $$\Omega^0_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d} \lambda^{-1}\Omega^1_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d}\lambda^{-2}\Omega^2_Y[[\lambda]] \xrightarrow{d} \cdots.$$
>
> This construction yields a $U(1)$-equivariant vector bundle $\mathcal F$ on $\mathbb P^1_{tw}$ [...] whose fibre at infinity is given by the Dolbeault cohomology group $\oplus_{p+q=n} H^p(Y; \Omega_Y^q)$, and whose fiber at every other point is given by the singular cohomology group $H^n_{sing}(Y(\mathbb C); \mathbb C)$.

How do I see that this modified complex gives Dolbeault cohomology?
I assume the construction of $\mathcal F$ relies on the Beauville-Laszlo theorem, which allows us to glue two sheaves on $\mathbb P^1_{tw} \setminus \{\infty\}$ and $\operatorname{Spf}\mathbb C[[\lambda]]$, respectively, which are isomorphic on the overlap $\operatorname{Spf}\mathbb C((\lambda))$, to get a sheaf on $\mathbb P^1_{tw}$. How do we construct the required isomorphism on $\operatorname{Spf}\mathbb C((\lambda))$?

I don't know much at all about formal schemes. Hints and partial solutions are very welcome!